# NPM - bower installation throws the error

Tags: node.js, npm, bower, bower-install

Using `npm` i installed the `bower`, but i got error on my `cmd`. how to fix this?

here is the error:

```
npm http 304 http://registry.npmjs.org/qs
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, lstat 'D:\Yeoman\node_modules\bower\node_modules\handleb
ars\node_modules\uglify-js\lib\mozilla-ast.js'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program File
s (x86)\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "bower"
npm ERR! cwd D:\Yeoman
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.28
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.9
npm ERR! path D:\Yeoman\node_modules\bower\node_modules\handlebars\node_modules\
uglify-js\lib\mozilla-ast.js
npm ERR! fstream_path D:\Yeoman\node_modules\bower\node_modules\handlebars\node_
modules\uglify-js\lib\mozilla-ast.js
npm ERR! fstream_type File
npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! fstream_stack C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modul
es\fstream\lib\writer.js:284:26
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/stringstream
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/mime-types
npm ERR! error rolling back Error: EPERM, unlink 'D:\Yeoman\node_modules\bower\n
ode_modules\handlebars\node_modules\optimist\example\short.js'
npm ERR! error rolling back  bower@1.3.9 { [Error: EPERM, unlink 'D:\Yeoman\node
_modules\bower\node_modules\handlebars\node_modules\optimist\example\short.js']
npm ERR! error rolling back   errno: 50,
npm ERR! error rolling back   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR! error rolling back   path: 'D:\\Yeoman\\node_modules\\bower\\node_modul
es\\handlebars\\node_modules\\optimist\\example\\short.js' }
npm ERR! Error: UNKNOWN, open 'C:\Users\mb112830\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\lodas
h\2.4.1\package\package.json'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program File
s (x86)\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "bower"
npm ERR! cwd D:\Yeoman
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.28
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.9
npm ERR! path C:\Users\mb112830\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\lodash\2.4.1\package\p
ackage.json
npm ERR! code UNKNOWN
npm ERR! errno -1
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/osx-release
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, lstat 'D:\Yeoman\node_modules\bower\node_modules\handleb
ars\node_modules\optimist\example\short.js'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program File
s (x86)\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "bower"
npm ERR! cwd D:\Yeoman
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.28
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.9
npm ERR! path D:\Yeoman\node_modules\bower\node_modules\handlebars\node_modules\
optimist\example\short.js
npm ERR! fstream_path D:\Yeoman\node_modules\bower\node_modules\handlebars\node_
modules\optimist\example\short.js
npm ERR! fstream_type File
npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! fstream_stack C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modul
es\fstream\lib\writer.js:284:26
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/lodash.isobject
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/punycode
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/nopt
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/core-util-is
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/registry-url
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/got
npm http 304 http://registry.npmjs.org/string_decoder
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/isarray
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/chainsaw
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/buffers
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/isarray/-/isarray-0.0.1.tgz
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/esprima
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/combined-stream
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/asn1
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, lstat 'D:\Yeoman\node_modules\bower\node_modules\update-
notifier\node_modules\configstore\node_modules\uuid\uuid.js'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program File
s (x86)\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "bower"
npm ERR! cwd D:\Yeoman
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.28
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.9
npm ERR! path D:\Yeoman\node_modules\bower\node_modules\update-notifier\node_mod
ules\configstore\node_modules\uuid\uuid.js
npm ERR! fstream_path D:\Yeoman\node_modules\bower\node_modules\update-notifier\
node_modules\configstore\node_modules\uuid\uuid.js
npm ERR! fstream_type File
npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! fstream_stack C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modul
es\fstream\lib\writer.js:284:26
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
```

Comment: You can try `npm cache clean` and reinstall bower

Comment: I wonder if [the race conditions mentioned in this `npm` issue on github](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/5857) are related.  Your npm version is older than the believed fixed version.